# Flip landscape UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a button in my UIViewController, I want to have Flip transaction when I press the button, I have transaction but it's flip portrait, would you please help me! 
I want to have it as Landscape

here is my code :

```
TestViewController *ctrl = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
[UIView transitionFromView:self.view
                    toView:ctrl.view
                  duration:1
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                completion:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:NO];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is illegal in any case. You may not transition your own view (`self.view`) out of the view hierarchy. Either transition a subview of `self.view` to a different subview of `self.view`, or else, if you want to use views belonging to view controllers, set up a system of parents and children and manage them properly (and, in general, call `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:`).

If what you're trying to do is summon the view of a different view controller, then use one of the methods that does that, such as `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

Comment: my button is in my first view controller and when I press button I want to have flip to load another UIViewController do you know any tutorial for this?

Comment: I've written you a whole book that tells you this stuff. See for example http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_presented_view_controller (feel free to read that whole chapter, explaining what a view controller is)